# Adding Products Not Adding to Product Code

Tags: php, arrays, cart

I have been looking all over stackoverflow for this answer but can't seem to find one that's relevant to this and it's really struggling me to come up with a solution to this problem.

The idea for this shopping cart is that every productid (from the database) is the key id for the array in a session (to try keep things relevant I suppose, it's all fine if all productid are unique), and if it does not find a productid in there it adds them, or on that row that it's found the same productid it adds one to it.

This is the logic:

```
$product_id = (int) $_POST['product_id'];
$qty = (is_numeric($_POST['qty'])) ? (int) $_POST['qty'] : 1;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = $product_id";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

if($result)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

    $product_id = (int) $row[0];

    $product_array = array('product_id' => $product_id,
                              'product_code' => $row[1],
                              'product_name' => $row[2],
                              'image' => $row[5],
                              'qty' => $qty,
                              'price' => $row[6]);

    // check if we've already got a cart key in the session array:
    if(isset($_SESSION['cart']))
    {
        // loops through the items to find the row of the product being added to the already there cart session:
        foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $k => $v)
        {
            // if the cart key which is based on the product id, is in the array, dont add it again
            if(in_array($k, $product_array))
            {
                // but add the desired qty to it:
                $_SESSION['cart'][$k]['qty'] += $qty;
            } else {
                // otherwise if it's not in the array, then add it like the one when we created the cart session key:
                $_SESSION['cart'][$product_array['product_id']] = $product_array;
            }
        }

    } else {
        // if not make one:
        $_SESSION['cart'][$product_array['product_id']] = $product_array;
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that if I say went to add product1 id of 1 to the cart, when I go to add product 2 (after adding product1 with the ID of 1) it seems to add one more quantity to the previous product and adds nothing to the cart, but another of the previous product.

I just don't get why this is happening, any replies are really very gratefully appreciated.

Jeremy.

Comment: Though if I was to go straight to product 2 and add that to the cart, then product 3 and then product 1 it works like it should, but if I was to go to yea (like i tried saying) product 1 when the session has been deleted and then try to add product 2 or 3 it just adds to the qty of product 1 for some weird unknown (to me anyway) reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I get to answering your question I have to mention the importance of security on the internet, and as such you should switch any database access code to [PHP's DBO library](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiysaTN17TLAhWB36YKHVN2ClUQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Fbook.pdo.php&usg=AFQjCNFIwSE1mNG_k_lj0510AL_SsZs5Vg&bvm=bv.116573086,d.dGY).

There are some really nice tutorials by NetTuts [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059) and [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059) and [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly--net-25338).  Besides making your code safer, it'll also make it easier, which I'll demonstrate.

The specific issue you were having I believe was this line `in_array($k, $product_array)`.  It wasn't comparing the arrays as you were expecting it too.  Thankfully, we can use the `$product_id` to access the data in the cart.

With the PDO changes and with accessing the cart using the `$product_id`, your code becomes more like this:

```
$product_id = (int) $_POST['product_id'];
$qty = (is_numeric($_POST['qty'])) ? (int) $_POST['qty'] : 1;

try {
  // create db connection and make sure db/sql errors raise exceptions
  $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ;

  // query the database
  $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id=:product_id");
  $query->execute(array('product_id' => $product_id));

  // fetch the first result as an associative array
  $product_array = $query->fetch();

  if ($product_array) {
    $product_id = $product_array['product_id'];
    $product_array['qty'] = $qty;

    // check if we've already got a cart key in the session array:
    if (isset($_SESSION['cart']) && isset($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id])) {
      $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]['qty'] += $qty;
    }
    // if not make one
    else {
      $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] = $product_array;
    }
  }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for that reply and yea I knew about the mysql functions being depreciated as it does give a depreciated warning, though this code was never going to be publically usable as such, it's more for me to fully understand how a cart should functionally work. Just really because I have been out of work for quite a while and was getting back into things and I couldn't find my old work I did where this was working.

Comment: Don't worry, it's just a general reminder for anyone who may stumble upon this Q&A.  I *always* put that at the start when writing PHP answers to questions that don't use PDO.  Some people may actually put unsafe code on the net, or may not even think about security) and that scares me.  The fact that so many tuts and examples and questions on the net use unsafe code just proves that it happens.  Never hurts to get into the habit of doing things right, especially considering it's super easy (and, in my opinion, makes the code cleaner and easier).

Comment: Just wanted to say a massive thanks for this, as expected works brilliantly, in hindsight though I don't know why I didn't think of this myself. Oh well it happens and at least if someone's having a very similar problem it helps them.

Thank you ever so much!